# Break up posts per page in two sections

Tags: custom-post-types, query, pagination

I have a custom post type called 'videos' and I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin with a select field to use as a filter to assign where the post part will display on my page. I have two columns, one called "our work' and one called 'featured films'. I need each section to display the latest 4 posts but when I change posts_per_page it affects the total number, is there a way to limit it to just 4 per query? Sub question is it ok to have the same query run two times? My code is :

```
<div class="triple ourWork col-sm-6">
    <h2>Our Work</h2>
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'videos', 'posts_per_page' 
=> 4) ) ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); /* start the loop */ ?>

<?php if( get_field('labeled_as') == 'our work' ): ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="">
        <?php global $post; 
            $gethref = $post->post_name;
        ?>
    <div class="holder" style="background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,rgb(38, 38, 42, .5),rgb(38, 38, 42, .5)), url(<?php echo the_field('screenshot'); ?>);"><a href="/<?php echo $gethref ?>"><span class="play"><?php the_title(); ?></span></a></div>
        <p><?php echo the_field('issue_short_description'); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<div class="triple featuredFilms col-sm-6">
    <h2>Featured Films</h2>
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'videos', 'posts_per_page' 
=> 4 ) ) ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); /* start the loop */ ?>

<?php if( get_field('labeled_as') == 'featured film' ): ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="">
        <?php global $post; 
            $gethref = $post->post_name;
        ?>
    <div class="holder" style="background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,rgb(38, 38, 42, .5),rgb(38, 38, 42, .5)), url(<?php echo the_field('screenshot'); ?>);"><a href="/<?php echo $gethref ?>"><span class="play"><?php the_title(); ?></span></a></div>
        <p><?php echo the_field('issue_short_description'); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this more difficult that it should be,

If I understand correctly you want to display the latest 4 'videos' which have been flagged as 'our work' in your first column and those flagged as 'featured film' in the next column, so you should actually add that [custom field parameter to your query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters),

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'videos',
  'posts_per_page' => 4 ,
  'meta_key' => 'labeled_as',
  'meta_value' => 'our work'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) { 
  //display your work videos
}
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'videos',
  'posts_per_page' => 4 ,
  'meta_key' => 'labeled_as',
  'meta_value' => 'featured film'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) { 
  //display your featured videos
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Notes:

1. [Reset your postdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Interacting_with_WP_Query) (last function call in the above example) this is important to ensure WP request continues as normal with the rest of your page.
2. Instead of using a custom field 'labelled_as' for your organising your 'videos' I would recommend you use a custom [taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies), this would allow you to leverage a lot more WP functionality at a later stage of your site development!

Comment: thanks! I'll look into the custom taxonomy as well.